# How can I make an "anti collision system" that blocks 2 things from overlapping in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, collision

Im learning programming myself and have made a test program in JavaScript using P5JS. I successfully made a collision detection system, but i want to make a system that makes it so 2 items cant collide with each other (like a car crashing into a wall, it wouldn't just go through the wall). I made the function that can do this but it seems really weak and unpolished, and i'm not really sure how i can improve on it. [Here is my code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-F5CHOIQvvGVlR3Njd1M1NLS1E), tips on how to improve that blockCollision() function would be helpful :)

Comment: Your question is too broad, also don't post links to your code from an off-site. Post relevant code in your question.

Comment: I linked my code that way because you'd have to use the actual program to see what I'm talking about when i say it feels weak and unpolished